# swift simple app always crashing on simulator

Tags: swift, crash, ios-simulator

My app is basically a webview with a locally stored webapp.

To support **URL-Scheme mapping**, I call the following function on `viewDidLoad`, to subscribe to `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification`, then when I get such message, I load a webapp into the `UIWebView`:

```
/**
* Setup the observer to get notifications about app activation
*/

func initObserver() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "initWebApp",
        name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
        object: nil);
}

/**
* Launches the WebApp, this is called from the observer, 
* and appDelegate.appParameters has possible parameters to the webapp
*/

func initWebApp() {
    var appDelegate=UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate;
    println ("- Launch Parameters: "+appDelegate.initParameters);
    let path=appDelegate.initParameters,
        url=NSURL(string: URL_BASE + "?" + (path ?? "")),
        requestObj=NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    mWebView.loadRequest(requestObj);

}
```

However, when I init the webview in this way (coming from the observed handler) the simulator always crashes with the stacktrace enclosed below as soon as I click anywhere on the window.

On the contrary, If **I don't subscribe to the event**, and just call `initWebApp()` from `viewDidLoad()`, everything works fine (obviously URL Scheme mapping doesn't work, but I mean the **webview and its app work 100% without crashing**)

Can anybody take a look at this stack trace (it's always the same) and give me any pointers?

Is it a bad practice to manipulate UI objects such as UIWebView from an event handler? (I come from Android where you often have to change threads in similar situations)

```
2015-04-06 02:49:34.907 FunqTV[14285:518122] -[NSURL _effectiveStatusBarStyleViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ae1cac0
2015-04-06 02:49:34.919 FunqTV[14285:518122] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL _effectiveStatusBarStyleViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ae1cac0'
*** First throw call stack:
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00648466 __exceptionPreprocess + 182
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x02037a97 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x006502c5 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 277
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00598bc7 ___forwarding___ + 1047
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0059878e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x00fd3fa8 +[UIViewController _currentStatusBarStyleViewController] + 75
    6   UIKit                               0x00e63c81 -[UIApplication _updateCurrentStatusBarViewControllerAppearance] + 59
    7   UIKit                               0x00eb06ea -[UIWindow _updateContextOrderingAndSetLayerHidden:] + 548
    8   UIKit                               0x00eade74 -[UIWindow _initWithFrame:debugName:scene:attached:] + 336
    9   UIKit                               0x00eadd1e -[UIWindow _initWithFrame:debugName:attached:] + 79
    10  UIKit                               0x00eadc7f -[UIWindow _initWithFrame:attached:] + 71
    11  UIKit                               0x011e6f27 -[UIAutoRotatingWindow _initWithFrame:attached:] + 80
    12  UIKit                               0x00eadc33 -[UIWindow initWithFrame:] + 63
    13  UIKit                               0x011e6eba -[UIAutoRotatingWindow initWithFrame:] + 72
    14  UIKit                               0x011e4e2a -[UITextEffectsWindow initWithFrame:] + 72
    15  UIKit                               0x00eae09a -[UIWindow initWithContentRect:] + 164
    16  UIKit                               0x011e4b12 -[UITextEffectsWindow(UIObjectsForPerScreen) _basicInitWithScreen:options:] + 141
    17  UIKit                               0x011e4bcf -[UITextEffectsWindow(UIObjectsForPerScreen) _initWithScreen:options:] + 182
    18  UIKit                               0x016fcf8c +[_UIObjectPerScreen objectOfClass:forScreen:withOptions:createIfNecessary:] + 556
    19  UIKit                               0x011e645c +[UITextEffectsWindow _sharedTextEffectsWindowforScreen:aboveStatusBar:allowHosted:matchesStatusBarOrientationOnAccess:] + 416
    20  UIKit                               0x011e65b4 +[UITextEffectsWindow sharedTextEffectsWindowForScreen:] + 121
    21  UIKit                               0x013d173a -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) containerWindow] + 156
    22  UIKit                               0x013d178a -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) containerRootController] + 34
    23  UIKit                               0x013c6e15 -[UIPeripheralHost currentState] + 38
    24  UIKit                               0x013c6f10 -[UIPeripheralHost isOnScreen] + 35
    25  UIKit                               0x013d3a6a -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) _isCoordinatingWithSystemGestures] + 82
    26  UIKit                               0x00e70da1 -[UIApplication _shouldDelayTouchesForControlCenter] + 56
    27  UIKit                               0x00ebd506 -[UIWindow _shouldDelayTouchForSystemGestures:] + 41
    28  UIKit                               0x0128f8e8 -[_UISystemGestureGateGestureRecognizer touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 498
    29  UIKit                               0x00eb3946 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 567
    30  UIKit                               0x00eb4abf -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 769
    31  UIKit                               0x00e79bb1 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    32  UIKit                               0x00e89bf6 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 21066
    33  UIKit                               0x00e5dbc7 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 2300
    34  CoreFoundation                      0x0056b98f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x0056149d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 253
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x005609f8 __CFRunLoopRun + 952
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x0056037b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 443
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x005601ab CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    39  GraphicsServices                    0x040152c1 GSEventRunModal + 192
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x040150fe GSEventRun + 104
    41  UIKit                               0x00e619b6 UIApplicationMain + 1526
    42  FunqTV                              0x0007dfbe top_level_code + 78
    43  FunqTV                              0x0007dffb main + 43
    44  libdyld.dylib                       0x027a5ac9 start + 1
    45  ???                                 0x00000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

[image]

Comment: you're right sir! added it

Comment: Could it be that I created groups to tidy up the project files and moved info.plist and storyboard to a group? before doing that everything was working. edit: PNG with storyboard and project files

Comment: hey Matt I found the issue, apparently I have to wrap the call to init the webview in a dispatch_async() block if coming from an observer. thanks for your help!

Comment: well I found this suggestion elsewhere, the idea is when Safari processes an URL Scheme mapped to my app, ie., `myapp://profiles/john` , i get a `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` , that I use it to open the webapp in a specific location. If you see something weird please tell me, this is my first IOS app ever :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I wrap the call to initWebApp() into a dispatch_async() block, it works:

```
   /**
    * Setup the observer to get notifications about app activation
    */

    func initObserver() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
            self,
            selector: "requestInitWebApp",
            name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification,
            object: nil);
    }

   /**
    * Called from the observer. It now dispatches async a call to the init
    * function rather than calling it directly from the observer thread.
    */

    func requestInitWebApp() {
        println ("Dispatching async call to init webview");
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.initWebApp();
        }
    }
```